# How can get status of Destroy funtion by Rail Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Code of `index.html.erb`: using ajax by  `remote:true`

```
 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.description %></td>         
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete, remote:true,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Code of `ArticlesController` :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    DatChat.reset_column_information()
    @dat_chat= DatChat.all    
    #render plain: @dat_chat.inspect
    return [@articles, @dat_chat]
  end
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end 
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy   
    redirect_to articles_path
  end
end
```

How can get status of Destroy funtion and show message delete `OK` or `Fail` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was resolved:
html:

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),remote: true,
              method: :delete,remote: true,class: "destroy-product",
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

code of `ArticlesController` :

```
>  @article = Article.find(params[:id])        
>      respond_to do |format| 
>       if @article.destroy            
>         format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "OK" }
>       else 
>         format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "Fail" }
>       end 
>      end
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
alert("<%= j flash[:notice] %>");

$('.destroy-product').bind('ajax:success', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
     respond_to do |format| 
      if @article.destroy 
        format.js {render locals: {message: "Ok"}}
      else
        format.js {render locals: {message: "Fail"}}
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do i have to create a Destroy.js.erb to catch result?

Comment: @DT Yes , it will render to `destroy.js.erb` there you will get `params[:status]` either ok or fail.

Comment: I don't think Ok/Fail are valid values for an http status code (which is what that `status` argument will be interpreted as)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think so it should be some `flash message` to confirm whether object  deleted or not, but as its requirement states, i have given the answer.

Comment: @Gabbar: I am quite sure this answer wouldn't work. `status` does not accept values Ok/Fail.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my bad, is it fine now?

Comment: @DT you can get `params[:message]` in `destroy.js.erb` to confirm whether object deleted or not.

Comment: i had try: alert("<%= params[:message] %>");  in destroy.js.erb . but it not working.

Comment: @DT So are you not getting `params[:message]` or is there any error at browser console or at rails server console?

Comment: error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Article with 'id'=8):

Comment: @DT Well it quite state forward that  object has been deleted already so , just refresh the page and try to delete another object. you are trying to delete an object which has already been deleted.

Comment: No, i change db to create 1 error. but can't catch message fail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171777/discussion-between-gabbar-and-d-t).